# JNI: Long-object created with wrong value

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am writing a c-jni function in Android, and I am having problems with creating a Long-object. I have succeeded in calling the constructor, but when I read the value of the object with longValue, I get the wrong result.

```
jmethodID longConstructor;
jmethodID longGetLongValue;
jclass cls;
jobject obj;

// Create a object of type Long.
cls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"java/lang/Long");
longConstructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"<init>","(J)V");
obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, longConstructor, 4242);

// Get the value by calling the function longValue.
longGetLongValue= (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"longValue","()J");
long return_long_value = (*env)->CallLongMethod(env, obj, longGetLongValue);

// Log the result.
LOGD("%li",  return_long_value);
```

I would expect that the above code would print 4242 in the log, however the value that is printed in the log is 1691768.

Does anybody have an idea on why 4242 is not written in the log?

Answer (score 3):

**<jni.h>** declares

```
typedef long long       jlong;          /* signed 64 bits */
```

Therefore, here is the fix:

```
obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, longConstructor, (jlong)4242); // or 4242ll

longGetLongValue= (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"longValue","()J");
long return_long_value = (*env)->CallLongMethod(env, obj, longGetLongValue);
jlong return_jlong_value = (*env)->CallLongMethod(env, obj, longGetLongValue);

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "test", "native t = %ld",  return_long_value);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "test", "native t = %lld",  return_jlong_value);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. Just cast the 4242 to jlong will work

Answer (score 1):

If you look at JNI mapping types, long in C is equivalent to jint therefore I think you should use java/lang/Integer instead of java/lang/Long.

```
// Create a object of type Integer
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID constructorId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject o = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, constructorId, 4242);

// Get the value by calling the function intValue.
jmethodID intValueMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "intValue", "()I");
long val = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, obj, intValueMethodId);

// Log the result.
LOGD("%d",  val);
```